# Is it somehow possible to prevent sshfs to create goutputstream files?

Tags: ssh, sshfs

Every time I use `sshfs` to securely mount a directory over the net, `sshfs` creates a lot of file like this one: `.goutputstream-YVG5CZ`

Over the time, the directory get's really messed up. Is there somehow a way to tell `sshfs` to stop creating those kind files?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/151101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not `sshfs` but an GTK-application which tried to access the folder. Due to apparmor-restrictions, it was not possible for the app to remove the `goutputstream` files. I changed the apparmor restrictions and the problem ist gone.

Answer (score 0):

@jeff-schaller is pointing you to an [askubuntu question/solution](https://askubuntu.com/q/151101), and though it is not the accepted solution to dealing with this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/984785), the [best option is from a user named belacqua](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151101/why-are-goutputstream-xxxxx-files-created-in-home-folder#answer-252025) who suggests running the following cron task *(where your user is "myuser", obviously replace that appropriately)*

`@daily  find /home/myuser/.goutputstream-* -mtime +2 -print | xargs rm -f`

In the bug report, back in 2015, Kenny Sharp responds in finality with

> At this point, with all the meaningless waffle and crap I just can't be bothered.

Which probably means this isn't going to be fixed soon - so, go for the cron cleanup.